# Help with creating a panel dataset

Tags: data-mining, data-cleaning

I have some medical information of individuals spanning ten years which includes first name, last name, dob, and other variables (two/three that could help match observations i.e. state living, education etc.). The problem is there are spelling errors in names, and chances of last name changing due to marriage, divorce etc. I also have some dubious entries of dob (date of birth). My strategy was to create a combined identifier of firstname,lastname, and dob and taking the string distance but not sure if that is a good strategy. Are there any libraries that could be more helpful given I also have other variables that might help class the observations.

The important point is that I need to make sure I have a panel dataset so all observations should be matched across years. Looking for the best ways to do this!

Comment: Help! Still need answers